# Safety of Calphalon pots and pans

Tags: equipment, food-safety, pan

I hear so many thoughts on Calphalon hard anodized pots and pans.  Are these safe to use?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are safe to use.

Even if you believe certain claims about metallic aluminum, the anodized coating is essentially [aluminum oxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide) which is very, very hard and very, very non-reactive.  So it is unlikely to enter your food either chemically or physically, nor to react with your body even if it did.  It is essentially *pre-reacted*.

This is the same material that rubies and sapphires are made of (not counting the impurities that give them their color).

The government sponsored sources all indicate any level of aluminum consumed from cookware is dwarfed by the amount of aluminum naturally occurring in foods in any case.  Some sources, especially the Health Canada ones use a lot of soft language, but always say there is no *known* risk—any risk that does exist will be quite small.

See also:

- [Michigan State University Extension](http://www.msue.msu.edu/objects/content_revision/download.cfm/revision_id.499708/workspace_id.-4/01500616.html/) article on cookware
- [Health Canada](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/hl-vs/iyh-vsv/prod/cook-cuisinier-eng.php#be), and [2nd Health Canada](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/fn-an/securit/addit/aluminum-eng.php)